# How to declare generic method in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to create a function that get a parameter of Class and return the instance of T,

so I have this signature:

```
public <T> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {}
```

Now, suppose I would like to limit `Class<T>` and to accept only `<T extends Command>`, so I tried this:

```
public <T> T foo(Class<T extends Command> clazz) {}
```

But, my class `Command` is also template as follow: `Command<S extends ModuleContex>`

So I try this:

```
public <T> T foo(Class<T extends Command<S extends ModuleContext>> clazz) {}
```

But this doesn't compile!

How to write it correctly??

Comment: (Called generics in Java.)

Comment: Well, it's a ["generic method"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) if you want Google to help you.

Answer (score 6):

Bounds for type parameters of generic classes or methods go on the type parameter, not uses of the type parameter:

```
public <T extends Command> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {}
```

If Command itself is also generic, you can do:

```
public <S, T extends Command<S>> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {}
```

and if you want to put a bound on S, you can do that too:

```
public <S extends ModuleContext, T extends Command<S>> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {}
```

Comment: I think they are saying that `Command` is itself generic. How do you get a `Class` instance for a generic type, parameterized the same way as the reference itself?

Comment: Just curious: why would you choose your third example over my answer?  Is there an difference?

Comment: For the 3rd answer - Eclipse gives a warning: "The type parameter T is hiding the type T"

Comment: @Shvalb Is there a type variable T in an enclosing class?  Is this method in some class Foo<T>?  If so, that's your problem -- just rename the inner type variable T.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: it only works if the concrete type represented by your `Class` instance is a non-generic type which implements the generic `interface Command`, e.g. `class Foo implements Command<Bar>` → `Foo f=foo(Foo.class);` or `Command<Bar> c=foo(Foo.class);`.

Answer (score 3):

This compiles for me.  I'm not 100% sure it's correct, you should test it with the actual types you use to make sure it works.

```
public class GenericMethodTest
{
   public static class SomeCommand<X> {}
   public static class SomeModule {}
   public <T extends SomeCommand<? extends SomeModule>> T getSomething( Class<T> type ) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice! it compiled perfectly! Thanks a lot! , but I see another answer which I prefer - the next one that takes 'S' into consideration.